# How to know in which scale i am from the notes of a melody?

Tags: scales, melody, beginner

Is there a way to know in which scale a melody is? I have no  musical lessons and i learned the minimum that i know from the internet but i think i have some basis (or i want to think it at least). My situation is i humm a melody, come to logic and play the melody in my keyboard. After that i try to play the chords but they don't sound good because I have no idea  on which scale i'm trying to work.  Is there a way to know in which scale is a melody from only the notes played?